# OpenGL Unhandled exception when using callbacks from mouse clicks vs mouse cursor moves

Tags: c++, opengl

Before asking the question, I will expose part of the code to explain it better.

I'm using `OpenGL 3.3` and `GLFW` for events from the mouse.

I have my OpenGL `class`:

```
class OpenGL
{
public:
    OpenGL();
    ~OpenGL();

private:
    //(...)
    void registerCallBacks();

    static void mouseMove(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
    static void mouseClick(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods);

    GLFWwindow*     m_window;
};
```

Where I register the `callbacks` for the mouse events.

```
void OpenGL::registerCallBacks()
{
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(m_window, this);

    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(m_window, mouseMove);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(m_window, mouseClick);
}
```

The methods called from the callbacks are these ones (which are `static` on the header file):

```
void OpenGL::mouseMove(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    void* userPointer = glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    Mouse* mousePointer = static_cast<Mouse*>(userPointer);
    mousePointer->move(xpos,ypos); //EXECUTE MOVE AND CRASH on glfwSwapBuffers()
}

void OpenGL::mouseClick(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    void* userPointer = glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);  
    Mouse* mousePointer = static_cast<Mouse*>(userPointer);
    mousePointer->click(button,action); //EXECUTE CLICK AND IT'S OK!!
}
```

As you can see, I have a Mouse class which handles the mouse events:

```
class Mouse
{
public:
    Mouse();

    ~Mouse();

    void click(const int button, const int action); //called from the mouseClick() in the OpenGL class
    void move(const double x, const double y); //called from the mouseMove()  in the OpenGL class

private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
};
```

Where the `move` method is only this:

```
void Mouse::move(const double x, const double y)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
}
```

And the `click` method is only this:

```
void Mouse::click(const int button, const int action)
{
    printf("button:%d, action:%d\n",button, action);
}
```

**My problem/question is:**

My openGL main loop has the: `glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);` at the end of the loop, which will crash on this line, if I use the `Mouse::move()` method as showned above.
If I comment the content of the `move()` method, there is no problem at all.

And I can even see the `printf's` from the `click()` correctly.

I see no difference between the move() and the click() methods...

What is happening here? Why is the crash appearing on the `glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);` only if I use the `move()`? And why not in the `click()` since both are constructed the same way, using their respective `callbacks`?

Note: I do need to use the `move()` method, to "save" the mouse coordinate, to use later on, on the `click()` method.

**The Error:**

```
Unhandled exception at 0x001F2F14 in TheGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4072822C.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting GLFW's user pointer to `this` of the object of class `OpenGL`, but in your callbacks, you cast it to class `Mouse`. There is also no inheritance relationship between those classes, so accessing any of the member variables or methods via that pointer results in undefined behavior, which expresses itself as a crash in your case.